# If image 'src' is '(unknown)' replace with 'missing.png'

Tags: javascript, image, replace

My CMS produces an img src="(unknown)" if an image isn't provided in the database. I would like to use javascript when this occurs to change it to img src="/images/missing.png"
As a complete JS noob I have tried several hacks but none seem to work... any ideas? (there is likely to be more than one image on the page if that makes any difference)

Comment: You need to explicitly post what you have done already.

Comment: And what CMS you are referring to? What didn't work?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This should work for you, if you use `onError` event for handling missing image `src`

```
<img src="main_img.png" onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='/images/missing.png';" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I used this to solve a similar problem I had (using javascript)...

```
const images = document.querySelectorAll("img");

images.forEach((image) => {
  let imgsrc = image.getAttribute("src");
  if (imgsrc === "") {
    image.src = "/images/missing.png";
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're using php then this problem is going happen for sure you can use `esc_url($url)`

esc_url function solves the problem

Answer (score -2):

If you're dynamically injecting the src when the page loads, you can always check and swap with placeholder if needed.

```
if (imgSrc === "unknown") {
    imgSrc = "placeholder.png";
}
```

Comment: This does not work if src value is (unknown) due to an error while loading, or if a src value is not provided. So this does not answer the question.